# ProxyPassReverse

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, java, reverse-proxy

our IT is trying to configure a new apache/jboss/apj setup. When I browse to  http://domain.com/jboss/test.jsp

and echo out the `request.getRequestURL()`
I get
http://domain.com/test.jsp
(without jboss) My deployed app encounteres a lot of 404's because of this.

This is what our IT department has the ProxyPassReverse set to.

```
<Location /jboss>
    ProxyPass balancer://cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID 
    ProxyPassReverse https://domain.com/jboss/
</Location>
```

Shouldn't the directive be set to:

```
<Location /jboss>
    ProxyPass balancer://cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID 
    ProxyPassReverse /jboss https://domain.com/jboss/
</Location>
```

Edit
The issue arrises when I use
`response.sendRedirect`

On our old server I used
`response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`

to get things to work with the new proxy I have to recode as
`response.sendRedirect("/jboss/AppName/login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`

My applications are no longer portable or reuseable with the latter syntax.  That line is in an my framework servlet for logging out and is shared by all of my apps.

The error (in Apache, not jboss) for
`response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`
File does not exist: /folder1/folder2/AppNamelogin.jsp`
Note there is no "/" between my appname and login.jsp

The error (in Apache, not jboss) for
`response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp?message=You have successfully logged off.");`
File does not exist: /folder1/folder2/login.jsp
Note the AppName is missing

Comment: Is the JBoss-server setup with the `/jboss` context?

Comment: I beleive so but I don't have access to directly view the apache configuration.  I'd have to ask IT but they always seem annoyed when developers ask them questions :) I'd like to just tell them here is what ProxyPassReverse should be set to.

Answer (score 1):

Nope; the first argument is implied when used in a `<Location>` block.  That usage is correct.

`ProxyPassReverse` serves only to translate the `Location` header on a `30x` redirection response; it's probably not the issue, given what you've described.

You should clarify exactly what the path *should* be set to.  If I understand you right, the request should be sent to `domain.com/jboss/test.jsp` instead of the current `domain.com/test.jsp`, right?  If that's the case, then just change..

```
ProxyPass balancer://cluster stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

..to..

```
ProxyPass balancer://cluster/jboss stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

**Edit**

Leaving the above in place, but the new information presented makes it clear that the problem is indeed with the `ProxyPassReverse` - the `balancer` configuration probably has the `/jboss` path in the `BalancerMember` configs.

Change..

```
ProxyPassReverse https://domain.com/jboss/
```

..to..

```
ProxyPassReverse https://domain.com/jboss
```

The slash is being stripped when the `Location` translation is occurring, sending the client a redirect to `/jbossappname` instead of `/jboss/appname`, due to the imbalanced trailing slashes between the `<Location /jboss>` and the `ProxyPassReverse`.

Comment: Shane. Correct. I expect the request.getRequestURL() to have jboss in the url. Or in other words what ever URL is typed in the Address bar, request.getRequestURL() should return an exact match. IT has our AS7 apps pointing to https://domain.com/jboss/App1 https://domain.com/jboss/App2

Comment: @jeff Right, but does it actually need to be on the non-`/jboss` path for the actual request to the JBoss server to map to the correct context path for your web application?  If it needs to have the path throughout, then make the change recommended in my answer and all should be well, but I'm confused at how the application code is even handling the request at all if an important part of the URL path is completely missing.

Comment: Not sure how to answer that.  I have edited my question to facilitate.

Comment: @jeff Ahh, then it is indeed an issue with the `ProxyPassReverse`.  See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Shane thanks I really appreciate you helping. But the error in apache never mentions /jboss as in /jbossappname. I was trying to anonymize my path, maybe a bit too much. file not found is more like this /WEB/wwws/appnamelogin.jsp

Comment: so.. I need clarification, do I change both ProxyPassReverse and ProxyPass? Didn't understand what you meant by "Leaving the above in place". Thanks!!!

Comment: @jeff What I meant by that is that I was going to leave the old version of the answer there instead of editing it out completely - but that difference in the path changes things.  Something doesn't add up - none of this config should be capable of removing the slash from that part of the URL string, in addition to having removed the `/jboss` from the path.  Is there any way you can get a more complete picture of the config?  Of particular interest is what's going on in the `<Proxy balancer://cluster>` section, as well as any other `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassReverse` settings.